# Unable to understand the string representation

Tags: python

Trying to understand existing code, i saw these 2 lines

```
key     = ']\n\x80\xd8\x13J\xe1\x96w\x82Kg\x1e\x83\x8a\xf4'
```

(the above value in **hexadecimal = 5d0a80d8 134ae196 77824b67 1e838af4**

```
data    = "p\xde\xdf-\xc4,\\\xbd:\x96\xf8\xa0\xb1\x14\x18\xb3`\x8dW3`J,\xd3j\xab\xc7\x0c\xe3\x19;\xb5\x15;\xe2\xd3\xc0m\xfd\xb2\xd1n\x9c5qX\xbejA\xd6\xb8a\xe4\x91\xdb?\xbf\xebQ\x8e\xfc\xf0H\xd7\xd5\x89Ss\x0f\xf3\x0c\x9e\xc4p\xff\xcdf=\xc3B\x01\xc3j\xdd\xc0\x11\x1c5\xb3\x8a\xfe\xe7\xcf\xdbX.71\xf8\xb4\xba\xa8\xd1\xa8\x9c\x06\xe8\x11\x99\xa9qb'\xbe4N\xfc\xb46\xdd\xd0\xf0\x96\xc0d\xc3\xb5\xe2\xc3\x99\x99?\xc7s\x94\xf9\xe0\x97 \xa8\x11\x85\x0e\xf2;.\xe0]\x9eas`\x9d\x86\xe1\xc0\xc1\x8e\xa5\x1a\x01*\x00\xbbA;\x9c\xb8\x18\x8ap<\xd6\xba\xe3\x1c\xc6{4\xb1\xb0\x00\x19\xe6\xa2\xb2\xa6\x90\xf0&q\xfe|\x9e\xf8\xde\xc0\tNS7cG\x8dX\xd2\xc5\xf5\xb8'\xa0\x14\x8cYH\xa9i1\xac\xf8OFZd\xe6,\xe7@\x07\xe9\x91\xe3~\xa8#\xfa\x0f\xb2\x19#\xb7\x99\x05\xb73\xb61\xe6\xc7\xd6\x86\n81\xac5\x1a\x9cs\x0cR\xffr\xd9\xd3\x08\xee\xdb\xab!\xfd\xe1C\xa0\xea\x17\xe2>\xdc\x1ft\xcb\xb3c\x8a 3\xaa\xa1Td\xea\xa738]\xbb\xebo\xd75\t\xb8W\xe6\xa4\x19\xdc\xa1\xd8\x90z\xf9w\xfb\xacM\xfa5\xec"
```

similarly the start of data is -
     7827fab2 2c000000 70dedf2d c42c5cbd 3a96f8a0 b11418b3 608d5733 604a2cd3

what is it representing , from the logic both of these should be sort byte string,

what I want to do is give value of key

```
key = 0a8b6bd8 d9b08b08 d64e32d1 817777fb
```

The value are hexa decimal (128 bit )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `binascii` module to move back and forth between the formats.

```
>>> from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
>>>
>>> key     = ']\n\x80\xd8\x13J\xe1\x96w\x82Kg\x1e\x83\x8a\xf4'
>>> hexlify(key)
'5d0a80d8134ae19677824b671e838af4'
>>> unhexlify(hexlify(key))
']\n\x80\xd8\x13J\xe1\x96w\x82Kg\x1e\x83\x8a\xf4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking "how do I convert this string of bytes '0a8b6bd8 d9b08b08 d64e32d1 817777fb' into a python string", here's the answer:

```
'0a8b6bd8 d9b08b08 d64e32d1 817777fb'.replace(" ", "").decode("hex")
```

Which will give you:

```
'\n\x8bk\xd8\xd9\xb0\x8b\x08\xd6N2\xd1\x81ww\xfb'
```